# How do you wrap a projection in custom html? Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

I have created a content type called CaseStudy and given it a field called HomepageLogo.

I want the logos to appear on the homepage. To do this I have added a Projection Widget into my AfterContent zone and onto to the homepage layer within widgets with a query to get me X amount of case studies to display.

Within my query I have the Raw layout selected with the wrapper container tag of "P" and class "logos".

What I am now needing is this wrapper to wrap everything

```
<div class="outer home-case-studies">
    <div class="inner"> {logos in here}
    </div>
</div>
```

When I put the above wrapper in Content-CaseStudy.HomepageSummary.cshtml I get the wrapper repeated many times over and there doesn't seem to be an alternate available to me "one level higher".

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Anto

Comment: While creating the query in the admin dashboard you can rewrite the HTML exactly as you want. This includes specifying custom HTML to insert before the first item when choosing the 'Raw' layout.

Comment: Was using the Raw layout the wrong thing to do? I don't see the re-write HTML anywhere only the HTML properties section which takes just one tag for the outer wrapper

Comment: In the layout overview of the Raw layout you can choose, which you did, to define a wrapper container. A few lines beneath that there is an option to prepend custom HTML before the first element that you render, for example insert `<div class="outer home-case-studies">` and append the closing `</div>` tag

Comment: aha! I feel so stupid lol! I had use the Prepend and Append on a different layout to add a title and view all button to a widget. Completely overlooked the idea of leaving div tags open in the prepend then closing them in the append! sometimes just takes a slap round the head haha :) thanks again devqon